# UITableView Not Showing Cells Properly unless scrolled

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

The UITableView is showing the cells, and they're loading the way they should be. However there is an image view inside of the cells, at aspect fit. They show full size until you scroll, and then scroll back up then it shows correctly.

Here are two images of what I am talking about. I tried reloading the data on ViewDidLoad as well.

When loaded: 
http://www.screencast.com/t/oj4xdQtyv

When scrolled, and scrolled back up:
http://www.screencast.com/t/0uHn5Wms53

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    imageIndex = indexPath.row

    var cell : CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.imgview.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 27, green: 27, blue: 27, alpha: 1.0)

    cell.imgview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    cell.imgview.layer.borderWidth = 2
    cell.imgview.image = UIImage(named: images[imageIndex]) /*Image provided*/
    cell.imgview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    cell.imgview.userInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.imgview.tag = imageIndex

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are using `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` and not `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate. The non index path version has issues with size classes and it looks like you initial cells think the screen is wider than it is. To do more will need to see the cell for row code and how you define the cell height.

Comment: I will add the code above now.

Comment: Your images seem very narrow? Have you made the table view narrower than then screen?

Comment: No, they only overlap and overflow like that on initial load, after scrolling it is fine.

Comment: Have you got any constraints on the UIImageView you are using? It would be worth making the top, bottom, leading and trailing edges be pinned a fixed offset from the containing view to constrain them. It should then resize based on the aspect ratio of the image loaded but stick to within the bounds.

Comment: Yep got all those set that's why it acts properly once scrolled

Comment: You could try calling setNeedsLayout then layoutIfNeeded on the cell before returning it. Long shot...

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Cell.contentView.setNeedsLayout then cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded.

Comment: That didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you the exact problem unless you post some code. But I can suggest a hack that will solve your problem.

**At the end of your viewWillAppear method try calling the function reloadData() on your table view**. This function just reloads all the cells of the data view. This will fix your problem.

One possible explaination about why table cells appear correctly once you scroll is that, once you scroll a cell out of the view the cell is basically recycled and hence it is reloaded with new data. So it resets the cell and it appears correctly. That is why calling reloadData method will solve your problem.

Post some code fragment, I will try to solve the problem without the hack. Also, check the settings of table view cell in storyboard it is probably because of those settings that this is happening.

Comment: I added my cellForRow method. :) I am going to try that hack now!

Comment: @AustinSweat have you created an outlet for table view in your controller?

Comment: Yes. @IBOutlet var myTableView

Comment: The delegates are connected, and so is the outlet.

Comment: @AustinSweat Are you sure you are calling the reloadData method correctly? Eg. tableView.reloadData() << here tableView is the variable you hooked up when you connected the outlet.

Comment: This is the method I am using: override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.imagesTableView.reloadData()
    }

Comment: Okay I had it in one of those but I will try that again. :)